# How to acces dynamic allocated through class object?

Tags: class, object, matrix, memory-management, dynamic-programming

i am working on a task where i need to acces a dynamically allocated memory to create a matrix.

If i did it correct, i reserved some memory for the size of my matrix and at the **setze_element** object of this **Matrix Class** i would like to use it to **assign my data.**
How could i write this line:

> *(matrx + i * spalten + j) = wert;

so the whole thing could work?

I would be really gratefull if you could help me with that.

I need this **HEADER File** to work at my **CPP File**, so maybe you could help me to find out how i could connect these two codes with eachother so they would work.

**HEADER FILE**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    

class Matrix

{

        
    public:
        Matrix(int zeilen, int spalten)
        {
        
            int* matrx = new int[zeilen * spalten];
            return matrx;
        }

        Matrix();
        Matrix(const Matrix &m);                 
        ~Matrix();

        Matrix operator = (const Matrix &m);    

        
        
        int setze_element(int zeilen, int spalten, double wert)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < spalten; j++) {
                    *(matrx + i * spalten + j) = wert;
                }
            }

        }


        
        
        
        double lese_element(int zeilen, int spalten, int &erfolg) const
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < spalten; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < zeilen; j++) {
                    cout << *(matrx + i * zeilen + j) << " ";        // oder (A + i*N)[j])
                }
                cout << endl;
            }

            // Speicher freigeben
            delete[] matrx;


        }
```

**CPP FILE**

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <iostream> using namespace std;


void belegen_m1(Matrix& m) {    double cmat[5][3] = { { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                          { 0.0, 2.0, 0.0 },
                          { 0.0, 0.0, 3.0 },
                          { 4.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                          { 0.0, 5.0, 0.0 }     };  for (int z = 0; z < m.zeilen(); z++)        for (int s = 0; s < m.spalten(); s++)           if (m.setze_element(z, s, cmat[z][s]) == 0)             {
                cout << "Fehler bei belegen_m1(), Abbruch" << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);             } }


int main() {    Matrix m1(5,3), m2(3,5);    Matrix m3, m4, m5, m6 ,m7;

    belegen_m1(m1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```